# XML Data load into SQL Server Special XML Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, openrowset

Okay so I am trying to load a large complex XML file into multiple tables. I am trying to drill down to one of the smallest nodes but then can't access the node above it.

```
use [ChaseDB]
DECLARE @x XML, @hdoc int, @Path varchar(1000), 
@SegmentNotePath varchar(1000)
SELECT @x=P 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\XML\XmlFilePractice.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) as 
Products(P)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

SET @Path= 'Root/Segment/OtherNode/SpecificNode'
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, @Path, 2)
WITH(
    SegmentID varchar(20) '../../@ID',
    SegmentName varchar(1000) '../../@Name',
    Note varchar(1000)'Note',
    NoteType varchar(50) '@Type',
    SpecificNode int '@ID',
)
```

Lets say the XML is like this:

```
<Root>
    <Segment ID="AS" Name="Amper Sands">
            <Notes>
                <Note></Note>
            </Notes>
            <OtherNode>
                <SpecificNode></SpecificNode>
            </OtherNode>
    </Segment>
 <Root>
```

So if my path is set to the SpecificNode, how can I access the Note? I know you can backup nodes with ../../, but how can you backup and drill back in, so to speak.

```
SET @Path= 'Root/Segment/OtherNode/SpecificNode'
```

Comment: `OPENXML` isn't necessarily the most convenient thing to use here. Consider skipping out on `sp_xml_preparedocument` and just using the native XML methods (`.query`, `.nodes`) so you can use arbitrary XPath every step of the way.

Comment: can you be more specific? How to implement?